# Verify my proof: $A \subseteq B$ iff $\mathscr P(A) \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm self learning from the book "How to Prove it" by Velleman (3rd edition). I don't have access to a math professor, so I need a little help from the community. Please verify my proof.

Problem 8 pag. 140

> Prove that  $A \subseteq B$ iff $\mathscr P(A) \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$

**Proof**. $(\to)$ Suppose $ A \subseteq B$. Let's take an arbitrary subset $x$ from $A$, then $x \subseteq B$. But also $x \in \mathscr P(A)$ and $x \in \mathscr P(B)$. But this is exactly what $ \mathscr P(A) \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$ means.

$(\gets)$ Suppose $ \mathscr P(A) \subseteq \mathscr P(B)$. Because $A \in \mathscr P(A)$, it means that $A \in \mathscr P(B)$ and also $A \subseteq B$ $\blacksquare$

Comment: Your argument in $\rightarrow$ is incomplete. What you are actually showing is that for each $x\in A$, if $x\in y$ and $y\in\mathscr{P}(A)$, then $y\in\mathscr{P}(B)$. But this is not what you are trying to show. What you are trying to show is that for every $y$, if $y\in\mathscr{P}(A)$ then $y\in\mathscr{P}(B)$. Your argument does not work when $y=\varnothing$. Instead, just start with $y\in\mathscr{P}(A)$; this means $y\subseteq A$; since $y\subseteq A\subseteq B$, then ....

Comment: Same problem with $\rightarrow$: what if there is no element $y$ with $y\in x$? Instead, why not just consider the fact that $A=\mathscr{P}(A)$? Since $A\in\mathscr{P}(A)\subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$, then $A\in\mathscr{P}(B)$, which means....

Comment: No, Where you say "because of" in the first part of your proof you are _assuming_ precisely what you are trying to prove.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think you mean $A$ is in the power set of $A$

Comment: @Math_Images_Only: Yes, that should have been $A\in\mathscr{P}(A)$... but it's too late to edit.

Comment: I took into account the input received from members and fixed the proof, also it became much simpler)

Answer (score 1):

You can be more economic on words which would simplify your reasoning.

When we want to prove inclusions $A \subset B$, the usual procedure is to take an arbitrary $x \in A$ and show that $x \in B$. This would imply that every element of $A$ will be an element of $B$, thus the inclusion.

In your case:

We want to prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$. Lets take $x \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ arbitrary and show that $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Indeed, let $x$ be such element in $\mathcal{P}(A)$. Now, $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$, means that $x \subset B$. Well, our hypothesis says that $A \subset B$, so any subset of $A$ will be a subset of $B$. And so, since $x \subset A$, this implies that $x \subset B$. Therefore, $x \in \mathcal{P}(B)$.

For the other direction we want to take $x \in A$ and try to prove $x \in B$ given $\mathcal{P}(A) \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$. I will leave this for you!

Good luck!

Comment: This is a correct solution to the problem, but not really an answer to the OP's question about their proof. That proof is incorrect - fixing it needs more than being more economical with words.

Comment: My answer has the intent to provide the OP the intuition for this type of problems, which imply doing the exercise again using what was written. Regarding being more economical with words, it is something that can and should be applied for later exercises.

Comment: The next to last paragraph says "we want to take $A\in B$"... I don't think that's what you meant. I think you meant "$x\in A$".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeah! Indeed, thanks for noticing! I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

As several others have commented, your proof is unnecessarily wordy.  There is no need to start each part of the proof with "We must prove that ..."  A literate reader knows what you need to prove.  There is no need to say "The premise $A \subseteq B$ means that ..."  A literate reader knows what it means.

A more serious problems is that you seem to have the parts of the proof backwards.  In the part labeled "$(\to)$", you seem to be assuming $\mathscr{P}(A)\subseteq\mathscr{P}(B)$ and trying to prove $A \subseteq B$, which is backwards.  Also, you write "Now let say there is a set $y$, such that $x \in y$.  If $y \subseteq A$, then ..."  But what if there is no such set $y$?  What if it's not the case that $y \subseteq A$?  You can't just assume things that you want to be true.

For the $(\to)$ part, your proof should have this form:  "Suppose $A \subseteq B$.  Suppose $x \in \mathscr{P}(A)$. ... [now prove $x \in \mathscr{P}(B)$]."  See if you can finish it now.

Comment: I've changed and fixed the proof, is it better now ?

Comment: The second half is good, although I think it would be clearer to start it by saying "Suppose $\mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$."  But in the first half, I don't understand the sentence "Because of the relation $\mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$, $y \in B$."  $\mathscr{P}(A) \subseteq \mathscr{P}(B)$ is what you're supposed to be proving; you seem to be trying to apply it.

Comment: I've modified the first part also. So this proof can be done without touching the elements of $A$ and $B$